# Hydra: interpolate variable from children node

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Given the following config files:

```yaml
# foo/bar.yaml
_target_: ChildClass
a: 0
b: 1
```

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
- foo: bar.yaml

_target_: MainClass
c: 2
d: ${foo.a}  # this line doesn't work
```

I would like to construct an object of type **MainClass**, which takes an object of type **ChildClass**.
One of the arguments of **ChildClass** is also used in the constructor of **MainClass**.

How can I read the child property `a` using argument interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea should work as-is.
Please make sure that you have Hydra version >= 1.1 installed, and give this a try:

```yaml
# foo/bar.yaml
_target_: mod.ChildClass
a: 0
b: 1
```

```yaml
# config.yaml
defaults:
- foo: bar.yaml

_target_: mod.MainClass
c: 2
d: ${foo.a}
```

```py
# mod.py
class ChildClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print(f"Child {a=} {b=}")


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, c, d, foo):
        print(f"Child {c=} {d=} {foo=}")
```

```py
# app.py
import hydra
from hydra.utils import instantiate
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf


@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="config")
def run(cfg: DictConfig):
    instantiate(cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

```
$ python app.py
Child a=0 b=1
Child c=2 d=0 foo=<mod.ChildClass object at 0x7f675436b130>
```